# Incrementing loop for filename to check if file exist PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, file-exists

I have this table column 'Data Status' where it will display 'ON SERVER' when it's corresponding control number data is on the said path.

But, the problem is it has a changing filename, based on the date of revision and software version.  For example: `'201909A17.txt'` - 201909 is the revision date and A17 is the software version (its extension is not `.txt` it's only a sample).

I have this PHP code, it's part of PDO but the data is only static and fixed:

```
$subfolder1 = 'folder1';
$subfolder2 = 'folder2';
$path = 'http://10.168.00.00:5000/Output';

$path2 =$path.'/'.$row["control_number"].'/'.$subfolder1.'/'.$subfolder2.'/'.$row["control_number"].'-201909A16.txt' ; // declare exact path of ps5 data

if (file_exist($path2)) {
    $tbody .= '<td rowspan="" style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;cursor:pointer" class="ON-SERVER" id="">ON SERVER</td>';
} else { //  IF FALSE 
    $tbody .= '<td rowspan="" style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;cursor:pointer" class="" id="">FILE NOT FOUND</td>';
}
```

How can I make a loop, where the revision date will start to `201901` and revision number start to `A01...`?  If the file name exist show to td `ON-SERVER`. And I want to limit the loop until value is `202012` and `A12` then it will output file not found.

**For example:** The file name of the data in server is `201909A16.txt` to  filter all the possible filename I need to start filtering from `201901A01.txt`, so that when it passed to `201909A16.txt` loop will be true and output `'ON SERVER'`

Simply saying I need to increment both revision date and the version of software, which makes me really hard to think.

I know I need to provide the code that I tried. But I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: So your file name changes from `A17.txt` to `201909A17.txt` on archive and you dont need to read the archive files. Isnt it? Can you make it clear with an example  please?

Comment: @Ajith file name will be from 201901A01.txt then incrementing up to 202012A12.txt.. so that it can filter the existing filename..

Comment: still not clear can you clear it with an example . Try with A17.txt names

Comment: @Ajith see my edit..